# problem to open connection to dbase database only in specific project

Tags: vb.net, oledb, foxpro, dbase

I'm trying to connect to a dBase (.dbf) database by VB.Net, I installed vfpoledb provider and use connection string like bellow :

```
  Dim cn As New OleDb.OleDbConnection With {.ConnectionString = "Provider=vfpoledb.1;Data Source=[MyAddress]"}
```

I got an error like this only in specific project :

> The 'vfpoledb.1' provider is not registered on the local machine

my project is compile on x86 platform and when I create a new project and use same code, everything is OK. only my main project got this error.

[both of my projects have same compiling options](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ONCJt.png)

Comment: Looking at [Visual FoxPro connection strings](https://www.connectionstrings.com/visual-foxpro/), it appears to me that the `.1` shouldn't be there, i.e. `.ConnectionString = "Provider=vfpoledb;Data Source=[MyAddress]"`.

Comment: A side note. You can pass the connection string directly to the constructor of the connection. No With or braces necessary.

Comment: Thanks for your attentions, I removed the .1 from my connection string and didn't happened any thing! I'm using this connection in other projects at this PC and its work well.

Comment: It might be worth checking again that it really is compiling for x86. Otherwise, would it be too much work to create a new project, confirm that the connection works, and transfer the code across to the new projet?

Comment: I believe that my project have problem or some wrong settings, I tested my projects on other PCs and every things was right! both projects compiling options are same.

Comment: Dear @AndrewMorton, My project is really big and I could NOT rebuild it, it's a very small plugin for that, maybe I write a DLL to do the job!

Comment: I'm very confused! I made a DLL that's work correctly on all projects except my main project! I try to add a reference named "Microsoft OLE DB Provider for Visual FoxPro 7.0 Type Library" to my main project but I got Error "could not be added"; it's worked on other projects!!

Comment: @user3080525 Have you tried re-installing the provider, in case it has become corrupted?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Getting the error "The 'VFPOLEDB.1' provider is not registered on the local machine" even after installing and registering the provider](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15684575/getting-the-error-the-vfpoledb-1-provider-is-not-registered-on-the-local-mach)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found the problem,
my main application must run as administrator but other projects run as current user, so I removed "Provider" and reinstalled it. I found that the default option on setup is "Just me"; I changed it to "Everyone" and the problem fixed.

[image: Select every one option]